# Entity Framework: Set navigation property with a local object (not saved to the database yet)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, bulkinsert

I am using Entity Framework version 6 and need to bulk insert thousand of object to a database in a very short time period.

Therefore I changed `DbContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled` to false and only use `SaveChanges` after many added items.

The entity, let's call it `Person`, has a navigation property to itself, e. g. `Supervisor`.

Now I want to add a person to the database and want to fill the navigation property with the supervisor that was just added to the context (just local, not in the database) an iteration before.

I just call SaveChanges() after 2000 thousand person because of performance. If I look into the database after `SaveChanges` the column `Supervisor` is always NULL. How do I add the navigation property?

Oddly enough my entity model has four navigation properties named `Supervisor1`, `Supervisor2`,  `Supervisor11` and  `Supervisor3`. Why does the entity model creates four navigation properties for one database constraint?

To explain my problem in detail: This is my 
[database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihbzi.png). EntityFramework creates [this model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fldo.png).

There is a loop to process data from a csv file:

```
     db.DbContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false; // for performance
    ///...    
    while (!parser.EndOfData)
    {                  
    // process data from a csv file with a name and a supervisorId             
        db.AddNewPerson(name, supervisorId);
    }
    db.SaveChanges();
    db.DbContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
```

And this is the data access layer method:

```
public void AddNewPerson(string name, long? supervisorId)
    {
        var dbSetPerson = dbContext.Set<Person>();
        var newPerson = new Person(name);
        dbSetPerson.Add(newPerson);

        if (supervisorId != null)
        {
            var supervisor = dbSetPerson.Local.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PersonId == supervisorId); // first look if the supervisor was just processed in this loop
            if (supervisor == null)
                supervisor = dbSetPerson.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PersonId == supervisorId); // if the was no person found look in the database
            if (supervisor != null)
                newPerson.Person2 = supervisor;
        }
    }
```

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Programming is the language of code, its easy to read an unambiguous. Questions like this suffer a little because its just a lump of text and its unclear exactly the code you are trying to run. Please consider editing this and adding a specific example so we know categorically what you are trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is, that the entity is not stored to the database at this stage and EF (proxy) does not know about it. What you can do, is to attach it, after you called StoreChanges():

```
yourContext.Persons.Attach(justAddedPerson);
```

But when you add some code, I can give more concrete answer.

**UPDATE**
Based on your edit (I guess that the Ids are int and not auto-created) I would suggest the following:

```
var persons = new List<Person>();
while (!parser.EndOfData)
{
    var person = new Person { Name = parser... }
    person.SupervisorId = parser...
    list.Add(person);
}

dbSet.AddRange(persons);

dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Do first the parsing and then the db operations. EF is clever enough to set navigation properties when you don't change the configuration and this should not be necessary anymore, because AddRange() should be much faster than Add() as it calls detectchanges only once. By setting the supervisor id only,

Comment: Could you please have a look again? I have added some code and further explanations.